# Catching a CF error when calling a CFC via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have an CF application that is using jQuery to call a cfc via `$.post`.  I have error handling in the cfc, but what about catching this example:

CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="function_1" access="remote" returnformat="json">
        ...
    </cffunction>
    ....
</cfcomponent>
```

CALLING PAGE:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...
        <script>
            $.post("mycfc.cfc",{
                method: "functio_1", //notice the misspelling
                ....
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will not cause a javascript error, and returns a 200 response.

The error would will be:

```
The method functio_1 was not found in component E:\inetpub\wwwroot\mycfc.cfc. Ensure that the method is defined, and that it is spelled correctly. <br>The error occurred on line -1.
```

I understand that this is basic example, and easily fixed, but I'm sure there are plenty of other examples where something similar could happen.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fix the misspelling. Your code is doing exactly what it should, you're just not handling the errors correctly.

Comment: The misspelling was deliberate to help describe the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To Handle missing function you can have a look at Ben Nadel's explanation of onMissingMethod() function http://www.bennadel.com/blog/868-Learning-ColdFusion-8-OnMissingMethod-Event-Handler.htm

You can always place this function in a parent class which can be extended by all your sub classes i.e. cfc.

So for example you can have object.cfc with this onMissingMethod() implementation and then all your cfc can extend it.

At the same time, if you wish to handle any other error in the ajax call, then you can create a standard return type structure from cfc for any ajax call and add a status field to it. So when you get any error in cfc then you can set the status to fail and when things are working then you can set the status to pass, which can be later handled by you in the ajax return functions.

Comment: I'll take a look at the `onMissingMethod()` function, and I'm going to have to adjust my ajax return handler a little bit.  I am returning a standard struct, but not really handling the error on the JS side very well.

Comment: @RobM I typically have an AJAX packet that looks like '{success: false, result: {data: }, errors: { } }' and if `success = false`, I would process the value of `errors`

Comment: @RobM You could also use jquery error handle to catch this error in javascript (.error(function(e) { alert(e.status); });)